# Django Hidden Redirection

Tags: python, django

I want to create a mechanism for in-app redirecting that would not quite redirect, but just load another view function. So let's say I'm going on `localhost:8000/a`, django renders the view and last line of the view says

```
return HttpResponseRedirect('/b')
```

So now my browser would go to `localhost:8000/b`, django would render view and return it to me.

Now I want to do that only on server side. So when I go to `localhost:8000/a` and django decides to redirect to `/b`, it renders view for `/b`, pushing it through all middlewares etc (so just like redirection would work) and return response without any redirections at all (as seen for user).

I have called such redirection `HttpResponseSmartRedirect` and it looks just like that:

```
class HttpResponseSmartRedirect(HttpResponseRedirect):
    pass
```

Now I want to create middleware for that (that runs as last of all middlewares), that on `process_response` checks if the response is instance of class `HttpResponseSmartRedirect`. Now my problem is - when I run into that situation - how to actually generate response with the view from the url? I can easily get view function by using `resolve()` from `urlsolvers`, but I don't know how to force it to go through all middlewares and create response identical to the one I'd get with casual redirection. The nastiest way of doing it is to just call `urllib2.get(url)`, but the looks of that line makes me want to destroy my computer.

Any ideas of how I can do it nicely without calling ugly `urllib`'s?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to re-inject the original request at the bottom of the Django request processing code.

Requests are processed starting at `BaseHandler.get_response` in `django.core.handlers.base`.

So the solution would be something like (untested!):

```
from django.core.handlers.base import BaseHandler

class SmartRedirectMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if isinstance(response, HttpSmartRedirectResponse):
           handler = BaseHandler()
           request.url = response.redirect_url
           resp = handler.get_response(request)
           return resp
```

For real use, you'd want some protection against redirect loops and infinite recursion.

Or you could solve the problem differently - let the browser do the re-fetch based on the redirect. If that needs to be invisible, it's easy enough to achieve with some client side Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

BaseHandler example (append slash without redirect, use it instead of CommonMiddleware, Django 2.1):

```
from django.http import HttpResponsePermanentRedirect, HttpRequest
from django.core.handlers.base import BaseHandler
from django.middleware.common import CommonMiddleware
from django.conf import settings


class HttpSmartRedirectResponse(HttpResponsePermanentRedirect):
    pass


class CommonMiddlewareAppendSlashWithoutRedirect(CommonMiddleware):
    """ This class converts HttpSmartRedirectResponse to the common response
        of Django view, without redirect.
    """
    response_redirect_class = HttpSmartRedirectResponse

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # create django request resolver
        self.handler = BaseHandler()

        # prevent recursive includes
        old = settings.MIDDLEWARE
        name = self.__module__ + '.' + self.__class__.__name__
        settings.MIDDLEWARE = [i for i in settings.MIDDLEWARE if i != name]

        self.handler.load_middleware()

        settings.MIDDLEWARE = old
        super(CommonMiddlewareAppendSlashWithoutRedirect, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        response = super(CommonMiddlewareAppendSlashWithoutRedirect, self).process_response(request, response)

        if isinstance(response, HttpSmartRedirectResponse):
            if not request.path.endswith('/'):
                request.path = request.path + '/'
            # we don't need query string in path_info because it's in request.GET already
            request.path_info = request.path
            response = self.handler.get_response(request)

        return response
```